# Google Kubernetes Engine deploy error with github actions

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, github-actions

I'm trying to deploy my code to GKE using github actions but getting an error during the deploy step:

[image]

Here is my deployment.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-3
  namespace: default
  labels:
    type: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
    - type: nginx 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
      - type: nginx 
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.14
        name: renderer
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Service.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-3-service
spec:
  ports:
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

And my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu/redis:5.0-20.04_beta

# Install.
RUN apt-get update &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata
RUN \
  sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y upgrade && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  apt-get install -y byobu curl git htop man unzip vim wget && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /root

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

This is what the cloud deployments(Workloads) looks like:
[image]

[image]

I'm trying to push a C++ code using an ubuntu image. I just want to simply push my code to google cloud kubernetes engine.

Update:
I've deleted the deployment and re-run the action and got this:

It said that deployment is successfully created but gives off another error:

```
deployment.apps/nginx-3 created
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "gke-deployment" not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
  labels:
    type: nginx  # <-- correct
spec:
  ...
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: nginx  # incorrect, remove the '-'
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: nginx  # incorrect, remove the '-' 
    spec:
      ...
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
...
spec:
  ...
  ports:
  - port: 80  # <-- add '-'
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

Comment: That is what we get when removing "-" : error: error validating "STDIN": error validating data: ValidationError(Service.spec.ports): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec.ports: got "map", expected "array"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer.

Comment: You mean service.yaml with your update, right?

Comment: After changing that, it failed on deploy : Run # replacing the image name in the k8s template
  
service/nginx-3-service created
Warning: Autopilot set default resource requests for Deployment default/nginx-3, as resource requests were not specified. See http://g.co/gke/autopilot-defaults.
The Deployment "nginx-3" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"my-app", "type":"nginx"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: `...LabelSelectorRequirement...field is immutable` - not every field of an existing deployment can be changed, eg. `spec.selector.matchLabels` is immutable once created.

Comment: So should we delete the cluster and deployment and create from scratch?

Comment: Just delete the existing deployment will do.

Comment: @gohm'c I did delete it, it said that deployment is successfully created but gives off another error: ```deployment.apps/nginx-3 created
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "gke-deployment" not found```

Comment: `deployment.apps/nginx-3 created` - the origin problem of this SO question is resolved.  `deployments.apps "gke-deployment" not found` - this is not related to this SO question. The screenshots indicated the cluster has insufficient resources, you should add node to your cluster.